# rownum / fetch first n rows

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

```
select * from Schem.Customer 
  where cust='20' and cust_id >= '890127'
  and rownum between 1 and 2 order by cust, cust_id;
```

Execution time appr 2 min 10 sec

```
   select * from Schem.Customer where cust='20' 
   and cust_id >= '890127' 
   order by cust, cust_id fetch first 2 rows only ;
```

Execution time appr 00.069 ms

The execution time is a huge difference but results are the same. My team is not adopting to later one. Don't ask why.

So what is the difference between Rownum and fetch first 2 rows and what should I do to improve or convince anyone to adopt.

DBMS : DB2 LUW

Comment: It may be the order in witch you have run the queries.  The first query may have also loaded schemm.customer into ram.  The 2nd query was only reading ram.  Try run each query 3 times for this one.  Or IBM hasn't optimized the row_number() function just yet.  By the way I've never had decent speed from any database with a function in a where clause.

Comment: I ran the query multiple times. I set up a monitor in prod to send email for queries > 2min and I captue the first query very often. I tested the same in STG. Same results.

Comment: "*what should I do to convince anyone to adopt*" - just show them those figures. But if DB2's rownum works anything like Oracle's, the first query is wrong to begin with - at least in Oracle the first one is not doing the same thing as the second one

Comment: There's no native `ROWNUM` in Db2, in the Oracle compatibility mode it is simulated using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, which obviously adds overhead.

Comment: Yep I've never had any luck with performance using a function in a where clause.

Answer (score 7):

Although both SQL end up giving same resultset, it only happens for your data. There is a great chance that resultset would be different. Let me explain why.

I will make your SQL a little simpler to make it simple to understand:

```
SELECT * FROM customer
WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

In this SQL, you want only first and second rows. That's fine. DB2 will optimize your query and never look rows beyond 2nd. Because only first 2 rows **qualify** your query.

Then you add `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM customer
WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
ORDER BY cust, cust_id;
```

In this case, DB2 first fetches 2 rows then order them by cust and cust_id. Then sends to client(you). So far so good. But what if you want to order by cust and cust_id first, then ask for first 2 rows? There is a great difference between them.

This is the simplified SQL for this case:

```
SELECT * FROM customer
ORDER BY cust, cust_id
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

In this SQL, **ALL rows qualify the query**, so DB2 fetches all of the rows, then sorts them, then sends first 2 rows to client.

In your case, both queries give same results because first 2 rows are already ordered by cust and cust_id. But it won't work if first 2 rows would have different cust and cust_id values.

A hint about this is `FETCH FIRST n ROWS` comes **after** order by, that means DB2 orders the result then retrieves first n rows.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer here:
https://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-rownum-vs-rownumber-and-12c-fetch-first/

> Now the index range scan is chosen, with the right cardinality estimation.
>   So which solution it the best one? I prefer row_number() for several reasons:
>   I like analytic functions. They have larger possibilities, such as setting the limit as a percentage of total number of rows for example.
>   11g documentation for rownum says:
>   The ROW_NUMBER built-in SQL function provides superior support for ordering the results of a query
>   12c allows the ANSI syntax ORDER BY…FETCH FIRST…ROWS ONLY which is translated to row_number() predicate
>   12c documentation for rownum adds:
>   The row_limiting_clause of the SELECT statement provides superior support
>   rownum has first_rows_n issues as well

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
SQL_ID 49m5a3f33cmd0, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */ * from test where contract_id=500 
order by start_validity fetch first 10 rows only
Plan hash value: 1912639229
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name    | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows | Buffers |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |         |      1 |        |     10 |      15 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |         |      1 |     10 |     10 |      15 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY       |         |      1 |     10 |     10 |      15 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST    |      1 |     10 |     11 |      15 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TEST_PK |      1 |        |     11 |       4 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber" <=10)
2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "TEST"."START_VALIDITY") <=10 )  
4 - access("CONTRACT_ID"=500)
```