# How do I rewrite the sql query

Tags: sql, query-optimization, oracle12c

I have a table ORDER with no index , partition , keys defined and I am executing below sql query to retrive the CODE starts with some value for first 200 mn records . It is taking too long to run .Is there any way I can rewrite this query.

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER WHERE  ROWNUM <= 200000000 AND ((CODE LIKE '1234423678%' ));
```

Comment: Are you able to add an index?

Comment: I can add index on CODE ..but still will it work..

Comment: First 200 million records with regard to _which_ column(s)?

Comment: matching CODE out of 200 mn records like 1234423678,12344236783,12344236787

Comment: No...I mean you are using `ROWNUM` without an `ORDER BY` clause.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes without order by clause the query should retrieve matching codes lime like 1234423678,12344236783,12344236787

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM ORDER 
    WHERE  ROWNUM <= 200000000 AND (SUBSTR(CODE,1,10) = '1234423678');
```

Not sure if that will make a difference, but perhaps it will.

Comment: Sorry @Kashi, my late night counting was off. I edited my answer with the correct character count of 10 in the substring instead of 9.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is:

> Use "FETCH FIRST 200000000 ROWS"

Source: [rownum / fetch first n rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520732/rownum-fetch-first-n-rows)

The real question however (as mentioned by Tim Biegeleisen) is that the retrieval results will be completely random as there is no sorting logic.